# Signup with passport & saving with Sequelize doesn't work (Unexpected ' ')

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, passport.js, postman

I have some problem with passport and sequelize on my Node.js project. 
In fact, when I want to signup, I'm using postman to call the /users/signup route and it show me : Unexpected '' and :

```
::1 - - [07/Aug/2018:09:20:19 +0000] "POST /users/signup HTTP/1.1" - - "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.2.0"
Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "username", "name", "firstname", "email", "type", "location", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "users" LIMIT 1;
```

There is the code :

```
/* CREATE an account */
  app.post('/users/signup', (req, res) => {

      db.users.find({ $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username }] }).then(user => {

  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  if (user) {
    if (user.email == req.body.email) {
      return res.send("This email is already taken.")
    }
    return res.send("This username is already taken.")
  }
  else {

    const data = {
      username: req.body.username,
      name: req.body.name,
      firstname: req.body.firstname,
      email: req.body.email,
      location: req.body.location,
      type: req.body.type,
      password: req.body.password
    };

    db.users.create({
      username: data.username,
      name: data.name,
      firstname: data.firstname,
      email: data.email,
      location: data.location,
      type: data.type,
      password: data.password

    }).then(newUser => {
      res.send("newUser saved to database")
      // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
      //TODO : res.redirect('/profile/' + req.body.username);
    })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).send("unable to save this newUser to database");
      })

  }

}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  res.status(400).send("signup failed");
})
```

})

And my model (db.users) :

```
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt-nodejs");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  // TABLE USERS
  const Users = sequelize.define('users', {

      user_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      },
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      firstname: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
          isEmail: true
        }
      },
      type: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      location: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
  });

  // methods ======================
  // generating a hash
  Users.generateHash = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
  };

  // checking if password is valid
  Users.validPassword = function (password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  };

  //hashing a password before saving it to the database
  Users.beforeCreate('save', function (next) {
    var user = this;
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      user.password = hash;
      next();
    })
  });

  return Users;
};
```

My **passport.js** :

```
// load all the things we need
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var db = require('../db')

// expose this function to our app using module.exports
module.exports = function (passport) {

    var User = db.users;
    // =========================================================================
    // passport session setup ==================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // required for persistent login sessions
    // passport needs ability to serialize and unserialize users out of session

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.id);
    });

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    User.find({
        where: { user_id: user_id }
    })
        .then(function (user) {
            done(err, user);
        }).catch(function (err) {
            return done(err);
        })
});


    // =========================================================================
    // LOCAL LOGIN =============================================================
    // =========================================================================
    // we are using named strategies since we have one for login and one for signup
    // by default, if there was no name, it would just be called 'local'

    passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
        usernameField: 'email',
        passwordField: 'password',
        passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
        function (req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form

            // find a user whose email is the same as the forms email
            // we are checking to see if the user trying to login already exists
            User.findOne({ email : email }, function (err, user) {
                // if there are any errors, return the error before anything else
                if (err)
                    return done(err);

                // if no user is found, return the message
                if (!user)
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'User not found.' }); // req.flash is the way to set flashdata using connect-flash
                // if the user is found but the password is wrong
                if (!user.validPassword(password))
                    return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' }); // create the loginMessage and save it to session as flashdata

                // all is well, return successful user
                return done(null, user);
            });

        }));

};
```

I can't find the source of the problem. I'm new with Node.js and I'm stuck since few hours. Is there someone here who can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

After discussion, we found out that the first error comes from the `beforeSave` hook on the User db model, where a hash function was used missing a `null` parameter as third parameter, and thus bcrypt was throwing a "no callback passed" error. There is several other things going wrong, such as missuses of promises and callbacks, and I suggest going through a learning of promises, and double checking documentation and examples on how to use the libraries, such as Sequelize and bcrypt (how to generate and use a salt for example).

---

#### Previous answer

I think the problem comes from your 'local-login' strategy : passport uses callbacks, but sequelize uses promises, so your `User.findOne` callback is never called. Try something like that :

```
app.post("/users/signup", (req, res) => {
  return db.users
    .find({
      $or: [
        {
          email: req.body.email
        },
        {
          username: req.body.username
        }
      ]
    })
    .then(user => {
      if (user) {
        if (user.email == req.body.email) {
          return res.send("This email is already taken.");
        }
        return res.send("This username is already taken.");
      } else {
        return db.users
          .create({
            username: req.body.username,
            name: req.body.name,
            firstname: req.body.firstname,
            email: req.body.email,
            location: req.body.location,
            type: req.body.type,
            password: req.body.password
          })
          .then(newUser => {
            res.send("newUser saved to database");
          });
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(400).send("unable to save this newUser to database");
    });
});
```

Same thing for the route, and the deserialize :
app.post('/users/signup', (req, res) => {

```
db.users.find({ $or: [{ email: req.body.email }, { username: req.body.username }] })
    .then(user=>{})
    .catch(err=>{})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i'm still having the same issue :/

Comment: updated. You should use promises everywhere you're using the sequelize model for queries. you did it for db.users.create, but not for db.users.find, so you never get the answer to find.

Comment: I updated up there like you said to me. But postman now tells me : Unexpected ' ' :/ I'm so lost right now..

Comment: Anyone can help me ?

Comment: you should try to have a simple functionality working before going full logic. Try to have just a post endpoint, creating a user and returning it. After that, you will focus on ensuring the user does not exist yet, and then you will check the passport strategies.

Comment: Updated with an example of how the route should work.

Comment: What does the server's log says ?

Comment: Executing (default): SELECT "user_id", "username", "name", "firstname", "email", "location", "type", "password", "createdAt", "updatedAt" FROM "users" AS "users" LIMIT 1;
No callback function was given.
::1 - - [08/Aug/2018:12:19:32 +0000] "POST /users/signup HTTP/1.1" 400 39 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.2.0"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177636/discussion-between-philippeauriach-and-steven-klinger).